# Credit Spread Replication by Long/ Short Bonds

Tags: fixed-income, bond, credit, bond-futures

I am trying to derive the credit spread using an hypothetical portfolio of a long corporate bond plus a short treasury bond, which have the exact cashflows. I should be able to get the credit spread in theory but they don't seem to match. Here are the assumptions.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| maturity | 2 yr |
| annualised coupon ( for both bonds) | 20 USD |
| face value | 100 USD |
| credit spread | 600 bps |
| t bond yield (first year) | 100 bps |
| t bond yield (second year) | 300 bps |
| t bond price now | 152.2404 |
| corporate bond now | 137.4558 |

I calculated the bond price with

[image]

where r = t bond yield (t bond) and t bond yield + spread (corp)

In theory I paid 137.4558 for the corporate bond and receive 152.2404 from the T bond, which leaves me 14.78466 USD in the bank account. How does that translate to the credit spread return? It doesn't match if I calculate it as (1 +  14.78466 / 100)^(1/2) = 7.1376013%. Am I missing the lending rate? If I calculate the lending rate using the t bond yield curve = 1.148529% and deduct, it gives me 5.6523%, which still doesn't match the credit spread.

Comment: 600 bps means a good chance that the corporte bond will default. Perhaps including probability of default (PD) and loss given default (LGD) in the calculations would make more economic sense.

Answer (score 2):

The approximate exposure to credit risk during the life of the bond = avg (bond price now,100) = approx 118.6.  6% of that is 7.12.   That seems quite close.

Comment: Thanks, but how does it work with the cash flows? Does it mean the credit risk in USD is calculated as avg(bond price now, 100) * (bond price now - t bond price now)?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Credit risk at time t = market value of Corp bond at time t

Comment: that doesn't make sense, shouldn't there be interest rate risk as well?